# The hessian and derivative with respect to vector

Tags: derivatives, hessian-matrix

I came across this, and I'm having difficulties understanding what the making means.

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n $ an open subset, $f\in C^2 (U\to\mathbb{R}).$   For every $x\in U$ mark $H(x)_{ij}=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial{x_i}\partial{x_j}}(x)$ . Assuming $x$ is a critical point, show that: 
$$<H(x)u,v>=\frac{\partial{f}^2}{\partial{u}\partial{v}}(x)$$

What I managed to get to so far (Left Hand Side):
$$\begin{align}
<H(x)u,v>=<\sum_{k=1}^{n}H(x)_{ik}u_k,v> = ... =\sum_{l=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial{x}_l\partial{x}_k}u_kv_l 
\end{align}$$

My questions:

- What does $\frac{\partial{f}^2}{\partial{u}\partial{v}}(x)$ mean in this context? a.k.a - what do I need to prove, and what does differantial according to a vector means?
- How/why do I use/need the fact that $x$ is a critial point in order to solve this?

Thank you,

Comment: Does $(\partial f / \partial u)(x)$ denote the directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ in direction $u$? That is $\lim_{t\to 0} (f(x+tu) - f(x)) / t$?

Comment: @user251257: I suppose it is partial derivative of $f$ with respect to variable $u$ at $x$ The function is a scalar isn't it? it says $f\in C^2(U \to \mathbb R)$

Comment: @mathreadler is there a $u$ or $v$ in $f$ or $x$? Does $\langle H(x) u, v\langle$ make sense for scalar $u,v$?

Comment: Yes you are right, there is some confusion here. Wonder if it is worth the effort to bust it.

Comment: This is for some arbitrary $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n $. Probably should have mentioned it.

Comment: @EitanAntler you use the notation $\frac {\partial f}{\partial \,\cdot\,}$ for two probably different things...